# Calculo en PHP mediante condicion

Tags: php, excel, matemáticas

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo donde calculo la cantidad de piezas que se necesitan para realizar un producto.
Tengo que cumplir la siguiente formula, el item 2 tienes hijos asi que los hijos depende de la cantidad de este padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero tengo el siguiente asunto cuando un un hijo de un padre tiene hijos necesito tomar la cantidad de este + la cantidad del madre.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código donde discrimino la receta. Pero el calculo no lo puedo hacer

```
$cantidad_orden = 10;
$query_orden = "SELECT x.* FROM Details x WHERE id  = 1 ORDER BY x.item ASC";
         $result    = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_orden);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $item = $row['item'];
             $cantidad_hijo = $row['cantidad'];
             $tipo = $row['tipo'];
               echo $item . ' >' .$tipo;
               echo "<br>";
               $level = substr_count($item, '.');
               $words  = explode(".", $item);
               $check_item = $words[0];

               if ($actual_item==$check_item) {
                       echo "Mismo item  ".PHP_EOL ;
                       if ($nivel_item==$level) {
                       } else {
                           $nivel_item = $level;
                           $cantidad_padre = $cantidad_padre * $cantidad_hijo;
                           echo "Otro nivel ::  ".PHP_EOL ;
                       }
                   } else {
                          $actual_item = $check_item;
                          $cantidad_padre = $cantidad_orden;
                          echo "Otro item  ".PHP_EOL ;
                   }
                   echo "<br>";
                   echo $cantidad_hijo .' * '. $cantidad_padre.' = '. $cantidad_hijo * $cantidad_padre;
                   echo "<br>";
             }
```

Si ejecuto ese código obtengo el siguiente resultado, disculpen la cantidades de fotos y el titulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco mejor el fin del ejercicio? Creo entender que se busca determinar cuántos insumos finales (sin hijos) componen un determinado producto.

Comment: @ffflabs El item `2` es el padre y los `2.` son sus hijos, pero el hijo `2.2` tiene hijos así que se debe aplicar la formula dicha en el excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

según como lo entendí debes multiplicar siempre por la cantidad del padre y del hijo incluyendo de los hijos a los cuales depende, adecuando tu código seria de esta forma

```
$cantidad_orden = 10;
$query_orden = "SELECT x.* FROM Details x WHERE id  = 1 ORDER BY x.item ASC";
    $result    = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_orden);
    $aux    = array(""=>1);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $item = $row['item'];
        $cantidad_hijo = $row['cantidad'];
        $tipo = $row['tipo'];
        $level = substr($item,0,strrpos($item,"."));
        $aux[$item]=$cantidad_hijo*$aux[$level];

        echo $item . ' >' .$tipo;
        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";
        echo $cantidad_hijo .' * '. $cantidad_orden .' * '. $aux[$level].' = '. $cantidad_hijo * $cantidad_orden * $aux[$level];
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

tambien podrias cambiar `$cantidad_hijo * $cantidad_orden * $aux[$level]` por `$cantidad_orden * $aux[$item]`

lo que hace este algoritmo es crear referencias anteriores de la cantidad del hijo y luego multiplicarla con la del hijo actual de esta forma todos los hijos tendrán una referencia implícita hacia sus padres

Comment: Me funciono muy bien mi budda, pero me puedes explicar un poco lo que hiciste con el $aux

Comment: @MoteCL `$aux` es un array asociativo que se inicializa con un índice vacío de valor 1 y luego vamos creando nuevos índices a partir de `$item`, `$level` almacena la parte padre de los items y consulta esas posiciones creadas

Comment: @MoteCL `$aux` se inicializa con una posición vacía debido a la respuesta de `substr()` cuando no se encuentra el "." en `strrpos($item,".")`